# How to look for a change in a file without polling?

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I have a beagle bone and want to read a the gpio pin from my program. The file either contains a 1 or a 0 at any given moment. In my C program I have a while loop that runs forever with a sleep function to keep it from being a cpu hog whenever that pin is low(0) and when it is high(1) it runs the the code. I feel this a very wasteful of resources. Is there a way that I can see when this file is a 1 and then run the code? I don't like polling, especially when the beagle bone is going to be battery powered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a notification mechanism, for example by utilizing [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html).

The basic idea is, that a callback is called, if data is available.

If this does not work you might need to use other APIs to get there, for example inotify.

Example courtesy of libev docs:

```
// a single header file is required
#include <ev.h>

#include <stdio.h> // for puts

// every watcher type has its own typedef'd struct
// with the name ev_TYPE
ev_io stdin_watcher;
ev_timer timeout_watcher;

// all watcher callbacks have a similar signature
// this callback is called when data is readable on stdin
static void
stdin_cb (EV_P_ ev_io *w, int revents)
{
 puts ("stdin ready");
 // for one-shot events, one must manually stop the watcher
 // with its corresponding stop function.
 ev_io_stop (EV_A_ w);

 // this causes all nested ev_run's to stop iterating
 ev_break (EV_A_ EVBREAK_ALL);
}

// another callback, this time for a time-out
static void
timeout_cb (EV_P_ ev_timer *w, int revents)
{
 puts ("timeout");
 // this causes the innermost ev_run to stop iterating
 ev_break (EV_A_ EVBREAK_ONE);
}

int
main (void)
{
 // use the default event loop unless you have special needs
 struct ev_loop *loop = EV_DEFAULT;

 // initialise an io watcher, then start it
 // this one will watch for stdin to become readable
 ev_io_init (&stdin_watcher, stdin_cb, /*STDIN_FILENO*/ 0, EV_READ);
 ev_io_start (loop, &stdin_watcher);

 // initialise a timer watcher, then start it
 // simple non-repeating 5.5 second timeout
 ev_timer_init (&timeout_watcher, timeout_cb, 5.5, 0.);
 ev_timer_start (loop, &timeout_watcher);

 // now wait for events to arrive
 ev_run (loop, 0);

 // break was called, so exit
 return 0;
}
```